# Visual Studio - Website solution files - Creating copies of website folders in the same directory as the .sln file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, web, solution

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio 2012 / TFS creating copies of website directories in the same directory as my solution file.

My repo structure is as follows;

Source code:

- /src/website1
- /src/website2
- /src/libraryxyz

Solution File:

- /sln/WebSites.sln

When I open up WebSites.sln in a fresh workspace, Visual Studio creates copies of /src/website1 and /src/website2 and places them in the /sln folder.

This only happens to the websites, the libraryxyz project remains referenced relatively. I've checked the solution file and the website reference is relative (..//src/website1).

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and how to stop it?

EDIT:
I have some more information on this issue;

- It went away after I created a new workspace and loaded the new
  solution from the new workspace.
- Creating a new solution with the same structure as described above for another website resulted in exactly the same issue reoccurring with the website folder.
- When the issue occurs, the actual folder mappings to the TFS repository are changed. That is, where the website directory would have a local folder mapping of, for arguments sake, c:\dev\ws1\src\website1, as soon as the solution is loaded, the actual mapping is changed to c:\dev\ws1\sln\website1 and the folder the website was previously mapped to becomes empty.
- A new workspace that now contains two new solution files using the new structure has the issue occuring only for the most recent solution. The previously 'fixed' solution works fine.

I'm really at a loss as to why this is happening, seems like the default behaviour until something is changed, I just don't know what that 'thing' is.

Comment: This is no doubt happening because you are using web sites instead of web application projects. It can be fixed by not using web sites.

Comment: It's a legacy system. Due to the state of it and some decisions that were made early on it's not possible to convert it to a web application.

Comment: I didn't mean to say it's the _only_ way to fix the problem - just the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we figured out what was causing this.

The solution file was not automatically being bound to source control.

File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control. Then ensure everything is bound to source control even if the bindings are deemed 'invalid.'